# Reason of not received packets in a transmission without channel-packet losses?

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I have a program that receives packets on a UDP-socket.

Here is the loop in which the packets are received:

```
clientfd = bind(client_s,(const sockaddr*) &client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));

    /*---Forever... ---*/
    while (1)
    {   
        addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);
            bufferWithPacketData = new char [headerSizeTot+symbol_size];
        int n = recvfrom (client_s, bufferWithPacketData, symbol_size + headerSizeTot, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&addrSenderOfVideo, &fromlen);
        if (n >= 0  ) //n=-1 => nothing receieved.. 
        {
        pthread_create(&threadID , NULL, &ProcessDataOfPacketInThread, (void*) bufferWithPacketData );
        }

    } //end of while
```

The code of the thread in which the packets are processed:

```
void* ProcessDataOfPacketInThread (void* ptr) 
 {
 char* bufferWithPacketData = (char*) ptr;
    pthread_t threadID;

                 //todo remove fprint messages..in the listener thread..
        //first byte containing which fec-session,etcetera..

        //todo remove print outs here

        unsigned int curr_fec_session = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithPacketData,POSITION_OF_FEC_SESSION);
   unsigned int fecSessionModuloNr = curr_fec_session % SIZE_OF_MAX_FEC_SESSIONS_AT_SAME_TIME;
        assert ( fecSessionModuloNr < SIZE_OF_MAX_FEC_SESSIONS_AT_SAME_TIME );

        //todo remove print outs here
            //i can do modulo elsewhere also...easiest..
        //   int fecSessionNrModulo = curr_fec_session % SIZE_OF_MAX_FEC_SESSIONS_AT_SAME_TIME;
        //one more symbol for this fec-session...
        //todo remove this if we are missing packets..

                int nrOfPktReceivedForCurrentSession;
                int nrOfPacketLossesForCurrentSession;
                float currentLostRate;

                unsigned int curr_symbol_nr = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithPacketData,POSITION_OF_SYMBOL_NR);

                  pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexForAccessSymbolAndEncodingAndNrReceivedVector[fecSessionModuloNr]);          
                  vectorOfNumberOfReceivedSymbolsForFecUnit [fecSessionModuloNr]++;
          nrOfPktReceivedForCurrentSession = vectorOfNumberOfReceivedSymbolsForFecUnit [fecSessionModuloNr];
               pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexForAccessSymbolAndEncodingAndNrReceivedVector[fecSessionModuloNr]);  
      //curr_fec_session == 0 &&
        //Do this in new threads all of the time to ensure that we are not blocked receiving new packets...

    //Run InitParameters-function, which will store parameters for the current fec-session in an array---necessary to use when decoding.Here we can also measure time...

           unsigned int session_sequence_nr = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithPacketData,POSITION_OF_SESSION_SEQUENCE_NR);

               fprintf (stderr, "\nProccessData; curr_fec_session %d; nrOfPktReceivedForCurrentSession %d; session_sequence_nr  %d; curr_symbol_nr %d",curr_fec_session,  nrOfPktReceivedForCurrentSession, session_sequence_nr, curr_symbol_nr  ); 


    //size vectorOfVetorWithEncodingSymbols == 0 in the beginning, so is curr_fec_session; check if curr_fec_session <
        //todo vectorOfvectorOfEncodingS0ymbolsTab ..decide order.
        //vectorOfvectorOfSymbolReceiveOrder contains receiver order..
        //i can have the same order for vectorOfvectorOfEncodingSymbolsTab ?
        //We need to expand!!! session=2, means we want size==3 to fit it..
        // curr_fec_session == 4 means we have expanded it ENOUGH!!



    //First packet of NEW SESSION!!!
                //only done one because of numberOfHighestFecSessionReceived =curr_fec_session below..
           if (curr_fec_session > numberOfHighestFecSessionReceived || ( nrOfPktReceivedForCurrentSession == 1  && curr_fec_session == 0 ) ) //First received packet. 
         {
                 pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexForAccessToHighestFecSessionNrReceived);
         numberOfHighestFecSessionReceived =curr_fec_session;
                 pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexForAccessToHighestFecSessionNrReceived);
                 fprintf (stderr, "CALLING INIT-PARAM");
                 InitParametersAndArraysForNewFecSession (bufferWithPacketData );
            //Erase old for the fec-session three sessions before current..

            if (curr_fec_session >= SIZE_OF_MAX_FEC_SESSIONS_AT_SAME_TIME -1  )
            {
            EraseVectorsForFecSessionModuloNr ( curr_fec_session);
                        fprintf (stderr, "Calling EraseVectors");
            }

            //Received packet of new session-> time to decode old session..Check that all threads performing insertion-elements to vector are finished inside of decoding....       
            //We are decoding the previous session !!
                        if ( curr_fec_session != 0 )
                        {
            DecodeFECSession( curr_fec_session -1);     
                        fprintf (stderr, "Calling Decode FEC-session");
                        }
         } //end of if.

        //Will always take place afte we have inited arrays..
    //Do this for all of the packets received.  
    InsertElementAtCertainPositionOfEncodingSymbolsVector ( bufferWithPacketData );
        fprintf (stderr, "Calling Insert element");


//lastLostRateSentToReceiverFloat

 } //end of method--called for each packet received..
```

One method called in the above method:

```
void InsertElementAtCertainPositionOfEncodingSymbolsVector (char* bufferWithDataAndHeader ) 
        {
        vector<char*>::iterator it;
        unsigned int curr_fec_session = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithDataAndHeader,POSITION_OF_FEC_SESSION);
       unsigned int fecSessionModuloNr = curr_fec_session % SIZE_OF_MAX_FEC_SESSIONS_AT_SAME_TIME;

        unsigned int session_sequence_nr = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithDataAndHeader,POSITION_OF_SESSION_SEQUENCE_NR);                             
        unsigned int curr_symbol_nr = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithDataAndHeader,POSITION_OF_SYMBOL_NR);

        unsigned int nrOfSrcSymbolsSent = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithDataAndHeader,POSITION_OF_NR_SRC_SYMBOLS);

        unsigned int nrOfRepairSymbolsSent = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithDataAndHeader,POSITION_OF_NR_REPAIR_SYMBOLS); 

        unsigned int totNrOfSymbols =  nrOfSrcSymbolsSent+nrOfRepairSymbolsSent;
        fprintf (stderr, "\nINSERT:curr_fec_session %d; session_sequence_nr %d",curr_fec_session, session_sequence_nr);
        //change the address of the buffer...
        bufferWithDataAndHeader += headerSizeTot;
        fprintf (stderr, "\nINSERT:first symbol of buffer data %d; second %d:", bufferWithDataAndHeader[0], bufferWithDataAndHeader[1] ) ;
        //strcpy (destination, source)         
        strcpy (charArrayofCharArrayOfEncodingSymbolsTab [fecSessionModuloNr][curr_symbol_nr ],
bufferWithDataAndHeader );
        fprintf (stderr, "after doing strcpy..........");
    //just commented out to do some testing how the code works without it...
      //   pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexForAccessSymbolAndEncodingAndNrReceivedVector[fecSessionModuloNr]); 

//          fprintf (stderr, "inside of mutex: adding symbol to SymbolReceiveOrder");

    //    vectorOfvectorOfSymbolReceiveOrder[fecSessionModuloNr].push_back (curr_symbol_nr);         
  //      fprintf (stderr, "releasing lock for encoding sectioN");
// pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexForAccessSymbolAndEncodingAndNrReceivedVector[fecSessionModuloNr]);    
    //   fprintf (stderr, "INSERT:after releasing lock!!");      
 }
```

One of the runs testing the program: The sender sends more than 512 packets. About the 100 first packets are received by the receiver. After that there is a gap of about 200 packets which are lost. An additional 30 packets are received with sequence numbers close to each other; and then the program terminates.

Modifying the code in order to test the behaviour without mutexes, shows that there still are many lost packets.

The program receives all packets with the following code:

```
while (1)
{   
    addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);
        bufferWithPacketData = new char [headerSizeTot+symbol_size];
    int n = recvfrom (client_s, bufferWithPacketData, symbol_size + headerSizeTot, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&addrSenderOfVideo, &fromlen);
    if (n >= 0  ) //n=-1 => nothing receieved.. 
    {
    nrReceived++;
     unsigned int session_sequence_nr = extract_value_from_header (bufferWithPacketData,POSITION_OF_SESSION_SEQUENCE_NR);        
    fprintf (stderr, "\nsession seq %d; nrReceived %d", session_sequence_nr, nrReceived);
    }
```

What's the reason of the missing packets and how do I resolve this problem?
My guess is that the program isn't running the thread with the `recvfrom`-command at every instance new packets are received by the socket, causing the lost packets.

**Some clarifications:**
I am sending the packets using loopback and there are no packet losses in the channel.
All packets are received when I have less code handling the packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite TCP, a UDP socket will not block at the `sendto()` if the receiver has not yet received the packet. So you sending packets with the max possible rate.

On the other hand the receive part may not be so fast when you create a thread (note that you create a thread for every message), so due to the unreliable nature of UDP, you lose packets. This may not happen when you just parse and print the received packet. Why you not try to reduce the sending rate by inject in your code a `sleep()` or `usleep()`, just to be sure.

Also you don't need to check for the case that `n` is equals to 0. This at a TCP socket means that the peer closed normally the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I now found out that only by adding a line which creates a thread (which does nothing) for each received packet, I reduce the number of received packets by more than half.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee with UDP. You should be using some other protocol such as TCP if you need a guarantee that packets sent will be received and that they will be received in the order they are sent.

Comment: Some clarifications:
I am sending the packets using loopback and there are no packet losses in the channel.
I get print-outs confirming all packets to be received when I have less code handling the packets.

Comment: Who told you there can be no loss in the loopback?! If you fill up the networking stack buffers due to the receiving process not being quick enough, it will drop packets, no doubt about that. You are overdesigning your system, it seems. Don't throw threads at the problem. First get a decently performing single-threaded application, figure out where the bottlenecks are, and only if you see it being CPU bound then create threads. In moderation. No more than two per CPU core -- the number of threads in your pool has to be adjusted to the configuration of the system you run on.